# Why can't I create a directory under /opt without sudo?

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo

Mac 10.11.5 (El Capitan) here. I just tried creating a directory under `/opt`:

```
myUser$ mkdir /opt/bupo
mkdir: /opt/bupo: Permission denied
```

Why would I need to prefix this with `sudo` and then authenticate myself in order for this command to work? If I *were* to use `sudo mkdir /opt/bupo`, then what user would actually be creating + owning this `bupo/` directory, would it be `root`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the root user can write to the root of the file system. So, it is safe to assume that the `/opt` directory is owned by root. The default `umask` would make that directory read, write, and executable to the owner;
read and executable to the group; read and executable to others/everyone.

If you use `sudo mkdir /opt/bupo` the directory would be owned by the root user.